# Take from array not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, find

Guy's what am i doing wrong here? 
Am trying to fetch an item from one array based of the value of a property in another object. 
I've tried to use .find and .filter and i get the wrong result. 
Either it returns the first item in the array as result or the declaration object, somewhere along the line am loosing the object that's meant to be fetched from the array.

```
  getContractTypes() {
this.recruitmentauthorisationservice.getContractTypes().subscribe(data => {
  this.contractTypesList = data;
  console.log(this.contractTypesList); // All object return succesfully

  let rTypeId = this.selectedRequest['rapRequestTypeId']; 
  console.log('rTypeId: ' + rTypeId); // Correct value of type number returned

  this.selectedRequestType = this.contractTypesList.filter(x => x.RAPRequestTypeId === this.selectedRequest.RAPRequestTypeId)[0];
  console.log(this.selectedRequestType); //Return's wrong object. i.e first item in the array

  //Tried a different way, this return's the empty declaration object when you console.log.
  // for (var i = 0; i < this.contractTypesList.length; i++) {
  //   console.log(this.contractTypesList[i]);
  //   if(this.contractTypesList[i].RAPRequestTypeId === this.selectedRequest['rapRequestTypeId']){
  //     this.selectedRequestType = this.contractTypesList[i];
  //   }
  // }
});
```

}

```
this.getContractTypes(); is being called in ngOnInit(){}

result object is initialiased like this:
  selectedRequestType: ContractType = {
    RAPRequestTypeId: 0,
    RAPRequestTypeTitle: ''
  };

and the object model is defines like this:
    export interface ContractType{
    RAPRequestTypeId?: number;
    RAPRequestTypeTitle?: string
}
```

Comment: Does it have anything to do with .subscribe() ? I've tried the code in and out of the service with no success.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the array before calling `filter`?

Comment: accessing jQuery objetc property works

Comment: this.selectedRequestType = this.contractTypesList.find(x => x['rapRequestTypeId'] == rTypeId);

Comment: @OlusegunOrija did you try with `this.contractTypesList.filter(x => x.RAPRequestTypeId === this.selectedRequest.rapRequestTypeId)[0];` instead of `this.selectedRequest.RAPRequestTypeId` what is the datatype for `rapRequestTypeId` in `this.selectedRequest` ?